# laravel DB::insert Invalid parameter number

Tags: php, database, laravel

I am trying to insert values of a form in my table by variables. 
When I try with one value it's ok but then with 2, this is not working.

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number (SQL: insert into ....

but here is my code and SQL request and I don t understand why this is not working.

```
DB::insert('insert into recherchesDuJour (UserIp,'."$ListeDesColonnesARemplir".') values (?,'."$ListeDesPointsDInterrogation".' )', [$UserIp , $ListeDesValeurs]);
```

My print_r of var

`print_r($ListeDesColonnesARemplir . '/');`

```
print_r($ListeDesValeurs . '/');
print_r($ListeDesPointsDInterrogation . '/');
die();

NaceCode,Langue/a:2:{i:0;s:4:"7724";i:1;s:4:"7762";},s:2:"fr";/?,?/
```

I have the same number of columns, "?" and values, so I don't understand.

Thanks for the help and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Please post the result of `dd('insert into recherchesDuJour (UserIp,'."$ListeDesColonnesARemplir".') values (?,'."$ListeDesPointsDInterrogation".' )');`.

Comment: so here is the print '"insert into recherchesDuJour (UserIp,NaceCode,Langue) values (?,?,? )"'

Comment: You have three `?` but only two values.

Comment: there is  3 $UserIp  is always there and then i add the others with my var that s why i have one ? too he is for $UserIp

Comment: What's the result of `dd($UserIp);`?

Comment: here it is "127.0.0.1"

Comment: I don't understand your previous comment. What's the third value?

Comment: so here i have 2 values =>   a:2:{i:0;s:4:"7724";i:1;s:4:"7762";},s:2:"fr"              and there is another one who is there every time $UserIp thats why there is $UserIp value and a ? who is directly in code and not in var

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert the `$ListeDesValeurs` string into an array:

```
DB::insert('...', array_merge([$UserIp], explode(',', $ListeDesValeurs)));
```

Comment: yes thank's i just do it in the same time and it works .